# Securely running LAMP under a specific user

Tags: permissions, users, apache-httpd, group, chmod

I'm setting up a sandbox type of server that will be used by a couple users as a development environment and knowledge base. The server will have a web frontend so I've installed Apache, MySQL and PHP.

Out of the box, everything under `/var/www` is owner by `root:root`. I haven't run a web server in a while but I'm pretty sure this isn't the best way of doing things. I vaguely remember the `www-data` user existing.

How can I get apache et al. to run as these users and have files in `/var/www` owned by that user and group (to which I can add my own user too)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each major OS distro supplies Apache preconfigured slightly differently. It's up to you to decide how you want your security to be configured.

If you're using a vendor supplied Apache package, try looking at the main .conf file (under Ubuntu it's called `apache2.conf`). Look for the `User` and `Group` directives. Either change the `User` and `Group` to the user/group that you want to own the files, or `chown -R <apache user>:<apache group> /var/www`.

If you're looking to allow multiple users to edit files in `/var/www` then you'll probably have to get creative. You could:

- Make sure that the files in `/var/www` have their group set to a group that all your editing users are in.
- Let editing users `sudo` to the www user to edit files.
- Set ACLs on the files in `/var/www` to permit users to edit specific files.

Comment: Welcome to the website! And thanks for your answer, it's exactly what I was looking for. Cheers.